# Calling Dynamic Screen Flows

Tags: lightning-aura-components, visual-workflow, automation, screen-flow

I have a screen flow that displays an agent script dynamically on a lead based its association to a campaign. This uses a parent flow with a decision element that routes to various subflows elements based on the flow api name that is embedded on the campaign record. Rather than use a decision, I would like to just have one element that receives the flow api name to call the subflow. I've seen solutions with apex that call a flow by url that opens in a separate window. However, I'm using the flow component on the record page to display the script and would like the subflow to run in the same context within the component view if possible.

Here are some solutions that I've tried already:

https://forcepanda.wordpress.com/2020/08/19/flow-action-call-subflow/

https://unofficialsf.com/dynamic-launching-of-screen-flows/

Thanks in advance for any suggestions,
Flow noob